# wget only download the index.html in each and every folder

Tags: wget

for example:

```
wget -m https://www.kali.org
```

No warnings, no errors; What can be wrong?

just to get more complicated I used the recommended command (see below) and the output is not satisfactory (yet):

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --domains=kali.org www.kali.org
Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only --convert-links will be used.
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2019-07-04 14:13:38--  https://www.kali.org/
Resolving www.kali.org (www.kali.org)... 192.124.249.10
Connecting to www.kali.org (www.kali.org)|192.124.249.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 18714 (18K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.kali.org/index.html.gz’

www.kali.org/index.html.gz      100%[=======================================================>]  18.28K  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s   

2019-07-04 14:13:38 (1.84 MB/s) - ‘www.kali.org/index.html.gz’ saved [18714/18714]

FINISHED --2019-07-04 14:13:38--
Total wall clock time: 0.3s
Downloaded: 1 files, 18K in 0.01s (1.84 MB/s)
Converting links in www.kali.org/index.html.gz... nothing to do.
Converted links in 1 files in 0 seconds.
```

But ... mirrored https://www.cnn.com - for instance

> Ubuntu 19.04 
> Codename: disco

some pages are loaded as "view page source":

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <link href='./index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>crontab.guru - the cron schedule expression editor</title>
  <meta name="description" content="An easy to use editor for crontab schedules.">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="QPa8OWuMuIsXgvuvPdfSCxA4ewd2Gs5tTUh0k2crBPE" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="/"><h1>crontab guru</h1></a>
<div class="blurb">
  <div>The quick and simple editor for cron schedule expressions by <a href="https://cronitor.io?utm_source=crontabguru&utm_campaign=cronitor_top" title="Cron job monitoring and observability" rel="nofollow">Cronitor</a></div>
</div>
<div id="content">loading...</div>
```

and again the tree directory was not downloaded.

`Check after 4 years and now works fine.`

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu are you having this trouble with?

Comment: Looks like the web-server is serving compressed pages to `wget`. Please see the Notice part of my updated answer below and use  the option `--compression=auto` so that `wget` handles the compressed pages correctly. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

This will work, it will copy the website locally.

If that is what you want, please use the command as follows ( change `domain.com` to your desired domain ):

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --domains=domain.com domain.com
```

- `--recursive` means: download the whole site.
- `--no-clobber` means: do not overwrite existing files.
- `--page-requisites` means: download all the components of the page including images.
- `--html-extension` means: save the pages as .html files.
- `--convert-links` means: convert all the links to run locally ie. offline.
- `--domains=domain.com` means: do not follow links outside this domain.

---

**Notice**:

Some web-servers use compression with served pages and `wget` will download a compressed file `index.html.gz` like so:

> 2019-07-04 14:13:38 (1.84 MB/s) - ‘domain.com/**index.html.gz**’ saved
>   [18714/18714]

In this case `wget` needs an extra option `--compression=auto` or `--compression=gzip` to correctly handle and decompress pages locally. You can use the command with this option like so ( change `domain.com` to your desired domain ):

```
wget --compression=auto --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --domains=domain.com domain.com
```

For further reading, please refer to [Wget - The non-interactive network downloader](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/wget.1.html)

Comment: Have you tried this command? It only grabs index.html, and does not follow any links, which I guess the user wants, as he's using mirror mode.

Comment: It will follow all the links, download them and convert to local links.  Fully brows-able website offline.

Comment: I tried it. [This is the full output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mfZshTMMHt/) from the command. It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: This is some of the output (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sqFwrdNq2R/)

Comment: Very interesting. The fact that it works for you, but not for me, might indicate that the asker has same issue. Would be interesting to know if asker is able to reproduce =)

Comment: @vidarlo It might be a version issue. I am using version `1.20.1`. Please run `wget --version` and update if your version is older.

Comment: I have tried with 1.18 and 1.19.5.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue.

Try this command:

```
wget --wait 1 -x -H -mk http://site.to.mirror/
```