# `wget` does not download all files for svn repository

Tags: wget, svn, xml

I tried to download all the data files (in .txt files) from the following link using `wget` at once.
https://svn.sdss.org/public/data/eboss/DR16cosmo/tags/v1_0_0/likelihoods/

Whatever I tried never succeeded. It only downloads the `index.html`. I am using ubuntu 20.04.
Interestingly, if I try to `wget` one single `.txt` files, it works. Any help to download all files at once?

Comment: That seems to be an SVN repo. Why abuse `wget` instead of using `svn`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that. What is the recommended method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wget only download the index.html in each and every folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155764/wget-only-download-the-index-html-in-each-and-every-folder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all of the files (and folders?) in that subversion repository, why not use a subversion client?

```
sudo apt install subversion
```

Then:

```
svn checkout https://svn.sdss.org/public/data/eboss/DR16cosmo/tags/v1_0_0/likelihoods/
```

This should give you everything in that directory and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `svn export` to copy individual files, using `--force` to clobber existing copies.

Sometimes, this method is handy when you want to pull files from a URL into a local folder, regardless if that folder is a checked out SVN workspace folder or not:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

set WMSBRANCH01=D:\YourWorkspace\MY_OTHER_SVN_FOLDER_NAME

call :svnexp !WMSBRANCH01!

goto end

@rem === BEG:Function:svnexp =======================================================================
:svnexp varname
SETLOCAL
if "noclass" EQU "noclass%~1" (
    echo Skipped svnexp called without an actual WMSBRANCH01 parameter value
) else (
    echo Copying SVN autoconf files from MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME in subversion repository to MY_OTHER_SVN_FOLDER_NAME workspace: %~1

    @rem Use SVN to 'export' the files into the BDEV workspace folder from SVN using a URL instead of copying the file from an existing 11.5.3 workspace folder
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ar-lib                      %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ar-lib
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ax_check_openssl.m4         %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ax_check_openssl.m4
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4    %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4 %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_17.m4 %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_17.m4
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/ax_pthread.m4               %~1\project\folder\build-aux\ax_pthread.m4
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/compile                     %~1\project\folder\build-aux\compile
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/config.guess                %~1\project\folder\build-aux\config.guess
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/config.sub                  %~1\project\folder\build-aux\config.sub
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/depcomp                     %~1\project\folder\build-aux\depcomp
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/install-sh                  %~1\project\folder\build-aux\install-sh
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/build-aux/missing                     %~1\project\folder\build-aux\missing
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/configure.ac                          %~1\project\folder\configure.ac
    svn export --force http://hostname.domain.com/svn/branches/MY_SVN_BRANCH_HAME/project/folder/Makefile.am                           %~1\project\folder\Makefile.am
)
ENDLOCAL
exit /b
@rem === END:Function:svnexp =======================================================================

:end
@echo Done!
```